# Grouping points when plotting multiple data frames in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data frames that I want to plot on the same graph. However, I would like to circle or enclose points (something similar to `ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse()` but any solution will do) that have the same row index. For example, if I have some data and make a plot like below:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 5, 2, 8 , 10),
                 y = c(5, 1, 8, 3, 8))


df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1.7, 5.8, 3, 7.5 , 9.2),
                  y = c(5.3, 1.1, 8, 3.6, 7.6))


df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1.2, 5.3, 1.8, 8.2 , 10.3),
                  y = c(5.1, 1.3, 7.6, 3.2, 8.2))


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y, col = 'red')) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, col = 'blue')) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

This creates a plot like this:
[image: example point plot]

What Im trying to do is circle the groups by their row index. That is, all row 1's   will be grouped together from all data frames... all row 2's will be grouped together etc.

I suspect I will have to somehow combine all the data frames... but Im not sure how exactly to do that!?
any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw the circles around groups of points, one way would be to use the `geom_encircle()` function from the `ggalt` package.  [Documentation link here.](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggalt/man/geom_encircle.html).

In order to implement that without some complicated plot code, you'll want to group your data frames together.  I'm going to assume you want to keep the colors of the points as you have.  The colors are mapped to the name for each dataframe, whereas you wanted the circles to be drawn based on the row position in each dataframe.  The most direct way to do this in my mind is to:  (1) add a column to each dataset that uses the `rownames()` function to designate the row of origin, and (2) combine the dataframes together, preserving the name for each dataframe.

### Add column for row names

Here's how I'm adding the row naming column.  This works best if you had a lot of data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggalt)

# make a group variable for each df and combine
df_list <- list("df" = df, "df1" = df1, "df2"=df2)
myfun <- function(x) {
  d <- x
  return(d %>% mutate(z=rownames(d)))
}
```

Alternatively, you can just add the column discretely to each data frame before combining in a list - which might be more straightforward if you only have a few data frames.

```
df$z <- rownames(df)
df1$z <- rownames(df1)
df2$z <- rownames(df2)

df_list <- list("df" = df, "df1" = df1, "df2" = df2)
```

### Combining the data frames

Combining the data frames using `bind_rows()` allows the usage of the `.id=` argument to add a special column that can link the observation back to the original data frame.  In this case, it's a new column called "origin", and the values for that column are taken from the names within `df_list`.

```
df_all <- bind_rows(lapply(df_list, function(x) {myfun(x)}), .id="origin")
```

### Plotting

Plotting is pretty straightforward now.  We can map the `color=` aesthetic to `origin`.  To draw the circles correctly, you need to specify the `group=` aesthetic to map to the `z` column.

```
ggplot(df_all, aes(x=x, y=y, color=origin)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle(aes(group=z), color="black")
```

[image]

If you don't want them all black, you can map `z` to a different aesthetic.

```
ggplot(df_all, aes(x=x, y=y, color=origin)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle(aes(fill=z), color=NA, alpha=0.2)
```

[image]